# How to count logged in clients with twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

How can I use twisted to query how many logins have been made on the server?

This is an short example for server side:

```
#Server side
def init():
   reactor.listenTCP(7921, XCanServerFactory())
   reactor.run()
```

This is a short example for client side:

```
#Client side
class MyApp(wx.App):
   def OnInit(self):
      messenger.registerConnectionWindowLauncher(self.chooseConnection)
      messenger.registerListWindowLauncher(self.chooseWindow)
      messenger.guiLaunchConnectionWindow()

      return True

   def chooseConnection(self, event = None):
      self.connectFrame = ConnectWindow(None, -1, "Connect to Server", shutdown)
      self.connectFrame.Fit()
      self.connectFrame.Show(1)
      self.connectFrame.connectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.connect)
      self.connectFrame.connectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.connect)
      return self.connectFrame

   def chooseWindow(self, event = None):
      self.chooseWinFrame = ListWindow(None, -1, "Example Window", 
            messenger, shutdown)
      self.chooseWinFrame.SetSize((240, 180))
      self.chooseWinFrame.Show(1)
      return self.chooseWinFrame

def init():
   app = MyApp(0)

   reactor.registerWxApp(app)
   reactor.run()
```

How can I exchange the number of logged-in users between server and client so that each client can see how many users are currently logged in?

I am interested in the exchange between client and server in order to inform each user in an output window of the number of users who have logged in. Of course, I need a login window where you log in and an output window where the information so and so many users have logged in is displayed. Of course, the complete source code is even more complex. If you are interested, you can see it [here](https://gitlab.com/horald/xcanasta). I would like to program a canasta game as a network program. If two users have logged on to the server, then two players should play together, if three users have logged on, then three players and so on. But how do I exchange this information with twisted, since the programs run on different computers and are only connected with a `connectTCP`?

---

Unfortunately, the advice that I should include the following function did not help me much:

```html
   def cmd_get_player_count(self, tag, args):
      # From where should this function be called?  
      print("cmd_get_player_count") 
      self.sendUntagged("playercount", len(GameRegistry.registry.getUserList()))
```

Where do I call this function in the server module? And where do I include it in the client module so that I can query the number of players? Please bear in mind that I have not programmed the functions myself, but have taken them over from another open-source game and am therefore not familiar with how this server-client technology works. And further, please give me an answer to these questions and do not give answers to questions I never asked! This goes off topic and is not very helpful!

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a very vague question and the code seems primarily concerned with setting up GUI widgets.  Where are you stuck?  The more specific, narrow, and precise you can make your question, the better will be the answers you get.

Comment: I put the comment that was longer than 255 characters now into the question. Better like this?

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification.  Unfortunately I assumed you had written the code linked.  At this point, it's probably a good idea to try to understand how the code that's there works before you try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked source repo, I see that you have a network protocol started already:

```
class XCanServerProtocol(basic.LineOnlyReceiver):
   def __init__(self):
      self._game            = None
      self._state           = "init"
      self._username        = None
      self._password        = None
      self._voteStart       = False
      # server messages to remote clients are in english by default,
      # unless the client uses the 'language' command
      self.trans = gettext.NullTranslations()



   def cmd_allplayers_admin(self, tag, args):
      for player in GameRegistry.registry.getUserList():
         self.sendUntagged("playername", player)
      self.sendOk(tag)
```

It seems like you're able to exchange some information between client and server this way.  If that's the case, the answer is to add a new protocol message that exchanges the new piece of information you want to transfer.

For example, perhaps you add a command like:

```
def cmd_get_player_count(self, tag, args):
    self.sendUntagged("playercount", len(GameRegistry.registry.getUserList()))
```

As an aside:

- You probably don't need to design your own protocol.  There are many existing protocols that work quite well and designing a good protocol is tricky.  For a start, HTTP is probably fine.
- You should use four space indents, not three space indents.  Approximately everyone uses four space indents.
- Try to keep your application logic (game logic, in this case) separate from your protocol code.  This makes both pieces more easily re-usable.
- Don't use wildcard imports (`from Game import *`) because it makes it hard to look up symbols (for humans and for tools).

Comment: I have expanded my question above once again.